# How to implement bulk update with sequelize?

Tags: sequelize.js, bulkupdate

I have tried here but I'm not getting correct answer this code will update only one record but I have to update multiple records at a time with different ids and I supposed to pass different ids as an endpoint to an API.

```
async function bulkupdate(req,res){

    var i;
    let successCount =0; 
    let errorCount = 0;
    var student = req.body;
    var id = req.params.id;

    const schema = {
        name : {type : "string" , optional : false , max :"100"},
        sem : {type : "number" , optional  : false },
        branch :{type : "string" , optional:false,max:"100"}
    
    }
    for(i=0;i<student.length;i++){
        const v = new validator();
        var result1 = await  v.validate(student[i] , schema);
        if(result1 === true){
            var result = await models.Student.update(student[i],{where :{id:id}});
            successCount++;
             
        }else{
            errorCount++
            return res.send({result1,errorCount,successCount})
            
            
        }
    }
    
    res.status(200).json({        
        successCount:successCount,
        errorCount:errorCount,  
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It updates one record because the value of id is the always the same,
if the request body includes the student id then you can use something similar to this

```
var result = await models.Student.update(student[i],{where :{id: student[i].id}});
```